# Examine the following functions $f_k:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ for continuity

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, continuity

I’m stuck with these math problems.

(i)$\qquad f_1(x):= \begin{cases}\frac{x^2-1}{x^3-3 x^2+2 x} & \text { if } x \notin\{0,1,2,3\} \\ -2 x & \text { if } x \in\{0,1,2,3\}\end{cases}$

(ii)$\qquad f_2(x):= \begin{cases}\frac{1}{x}-\left\lfloor\frac{1}{x}\right\rfloor & \text { if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text { if } x=0\end{cases}$

(iii)$\qquad f_3(x):= \begin{cases}x & \text { if } x \in \mathbb{Q} \\ 1 & \text { if } x \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$

I know that I have to check the definition, the limits and the function value at each point, but I still have problems:

For (i), I don’t know how to calculate the limits. I tried to simplify the numerator and the denominator by dividing by (x-1), but that didn’t work. And how do I deal with the floor function in (ii)? I tried to simplify the fraction by replacing it with a variable z, but that didn’t work well. And how do I handle the rational and irrational numbers in (iii)? Can I simplify the function by replacing the set of rational numbers with a subset A?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: for first limit
$x^2 - 1 = (x - 1)(x + 1)$ and $x^3 - 3x^2 + 2x = x(x^2 - 3x + 2) = x(x - 1)(x -2)$
it might not exist or be infinite in some points

Comment: For second one ..draw the graph of the fractional part of $1/x$

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to calculate the limits? You should have learned how to calculate limits of rational functions in calculus, and this is clearly a real analysis problem. And in what way did simplifying by dividing out by $x-1$ "not work"? Be specific about what issues you are having. For (iii) how would replacing $\Bbb Q$ by a subset be useful in the slightest? If a function is continuous, then in any small enough neighborhood of a point $x = a$, the values of $f(x)$ must all be near to $f(a)$. There is only one value of $x$ where this could possibly be true for $f_3$.